# Read large files and send to jms queue using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a scenario to read a huge file and send the records to a jms queue for further processing. 
The file can be ***CSV/FIX*** format.  I am planning to use Spring batch to achieve the same. 
I read about **MultiResourcePartitioner** for reading huge file when we use *spring batch*.

Is it a good idea to use *spring batch* in this scenario? Or should I use plain java code to read huge file? Or is there any other better approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Spring Batch is a good choice for your use case for a couple of reasons:

- You can use the `FlatFileItemReader` and `JmsItemWriter` out-of-the-box (in comparison to writing this code yourself if you use plain Java)
- You will have several scaling options (see below)
- The chunk-oriented processing model is suitable for huge data sets like in your use case
- And many other features for free (transaction management, restartability, etc)

Physically partitioning the input file into multiple resources and using the `MultiResourcePartitioner` is indeed a good option for your use case. However, this is not the only way to scale a chunk-oriented step in Spring Batch, you can also use:

- A [multi-threaded step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) where each chunk is processed in a separate thread
- A combination of the [`AsyncItemProcessor`/`AsyncItemWriter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#asynchronous-processors) (useful if you have some heavy processing to do on items before writing them to the queue)

The previous 3 scaling techniques are implemented within a single JVM. There are other options to scale a batch job across multiple JVMs like remote chunking and remote partitioning (but those are not required IMO for your use case).

You can find a talk about all these scaling techniques with code examples here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6IPlfm7N6w

Hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate your quick response. let me try using the same approach.!